# Optimize memcpy on Windows (MSVC++)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memcpy

Let's say I want to copy #SIZE no. of integers from one array to another. I see that the performance of the following 3 are different, even though they accomplish the same job:

```
memcpy((char*)(arr), (char*)(temp), sizeof(int) * size);
memcpy((int*)(arr), (int*)(temp), size);
memcpy((double*)(arr), (double*)(temp), size/(sizeof(double)/sizeof(int)));
```

The timings are 160 us, 40 us and 20 us respectively (for a size of 1 million integers). I understand that the use of registers would be of different sizes in each case, but I was expecting MSVC compiler to optimize all of these by using the highest (vector) register size. Memory alignment could be achieved by creating peel and remainder loops. Also there is possibility of using non-temporal/streaming stores. Is there a way to force this optimization in the compiler?

Also, is there any way to force inlining of memcpy in MSVC?

Comment: The result is suggesting that the smaller the size to copy, the shorter the elapsed time is. 2nd and 3rd call of `memcpy()` won't do what you want (copy `size` integers).

Comment: The third argument of memcpy is in bytes. Those three statements are copying different amounts of memory.

Comment: Or are you using non-standard `memcpy` (like a macro defined by yourself)?

Comment: All of those casts you're doing in the first two arguments are superfluous.  The `memcpy` takes `void` pointers for the first two arguments, so there is no need for casting.

Comment: Also, using typesafe `std::copy` will or should boil down to `memcpy` in any good optimizing compiler.  Maybe you should use that instead of casting in so many places.

Comment: Thank you all. Such a silly mistake of not reading the documentation properly and missing out by assumptions. I had a test to check the end points of the array whether its copied completely but I found I've made an error and was checking the wrong array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memcpy` always copies bytes, while you seem to assume that it copies the type you pass (`int` or `double`). From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

> Copies count **bytes** from the object pointed to by src to the object pointed to by dest. Both objects are reinterpreted as arrays of unsigned char.

As your three calls do copy different amount of bytes the difference in runtime is to be expected. If `sizeof(int) == 4` and `double` is twice the size of an `int` on your platform, the times you measured are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

> even though they accomplish the same job

No, that is not true.

The last parameter of `memcpy` is the length, **in bytes**, not in number of items. Your second line does four times less work, copying only a quarter of what you want (or the first one copies four time too much).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers explain the problem well, I would just add some numbers for clarification:

```
memcpy((char*)(arr), (char*)(temp), sizeof(int) * size);
```

The first call copies `sizeof(int) * size` bytes which is likely **`4 * size` bytes**. It takes **160 microseconds**.

```
memcpy((int*)(arr), (int*)(temp), size);
```

The second call copies **`size` bytes**, therefore 4 times less, and it also takes 4 times less time, namely 160/4 = **40 microseconds**.

```
memcpy((double*)(arr), (double*)(temp), size/(sizeof(double)/sizeof(int)));
```

The third call copies `size/(sizeof(double)/sizeof(int))` bytes, which is likely `size/(8/4)`, therefore **`size/2` bytes**. This is eight and two times less than in the first and second case, respectively. It takes 160/8 = 40/2 = **20 microseconds**.

The runtime is therefore exactly proportional to the number of copied bytes.